# Merging different size data frames and repeating values

Tags: r, merge

I need to merge two different size data frames. The larger one (`df1`) has a column with several repeated values (`licto`), the shorter one (`df2`) has the column `licto`, but its values are not repeated. df2 also has a ID column. I need a new column in `df1` with the IDs in `df2`, repeated according the repeated values in `licto`. The example below probably make it clearer.

```
df1<-data.frame(licfrom=c(15470,16307,17121,15350,16982,17182,20319,16727,16946,16262,16605,
              16607,15924,15399,15404,16739,16839,16842,16899,16157,15399),
        licto=c(17121,17121,17121,16982,16982,16982,16982,16946,16946,16262,16607,
            16607,15924,16839,16839,16839,16839,16839,16839,16157,15399))
```

.

```
df2<-data.frame(licto=c(17121,16982,16946,16607,15924,16839,16157,15399),
        fisherID=c(160,760,770,406,106,2196,17323,2441))
```

My data frames look like this:

```
df1                 df2 
licfrom licto       licto   fisherID
15470   17121       17121   160
16307   17121       16982   760
17121   17121       16946   770
15350   16982       16262   947
16982   16982       16607   406
17182   16982       15924   106
20319   16982       16839   2196
16727   16946       16157   17323
16946   16946       15399   2441
16262   16262           
16605   16607           
16607   16607           
15924   15924           
15399   16839           
15404   16839           
16739   16839           
16839   16839           
16842   16839           
16899   16839           
16157   16157           
15399   15399
```

And my final data frame should be like this:

```
licfrom licto   fisherID
15470   17121   160
16307   17121   160
17121   17121   160
15350   16982   760
16982   16982   760
17182   16982   760
20319   16982   760
16727   16946   770
16946   16946   770
16262   16262   947
16605   16607   406
16607   16607   406
15924   15924   106
15399   16839   2196
15404   16839   2196
16739   16839   2196
16839   16839   2196
16842   16839   2196
16899   16839   2196
16157   16157   17323
15399   15399   2441
```

Any help will be appreciated, as I have spent several hour trying to merge as I need. I have used `merge` and  `%in%` with no success. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it simply with function `merge()`.

```
 merge(df1,df2,sort=FALSE)

   licto licfrom fisherID
1  17121   15470      160
2  17121   17121      160
3  17121   16307      160
4  16982   15350      760
5  16982   16982      760
6  16982   20319      760
7  16982   17182      760
8  16946   16727      770
9  16946   16946      770
10 16607   16605      406
11 16607   16607      406
12 15924   15924      106
13 16839   15399     2196
14 16839   15404     2196
15 16839   16739     2196
16 16839   16839     2196
17 16839   16842     2196
18 16839   16899     2196
19 16157   16157    17323
20 15399   15399     2441
```

Comment: It was simpler than I thought, just adding the sort argument it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

To be more explicit with the options, you might want to try this

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "licto", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is more of a comment on the previous answer than a new answer.